# What about a tag for 70AD?

Tags: discussion

I could add a tag by myself but I don't want to do it thoughtlessly. Much of the scriptures pertain to the Great Revolt/First Jewish-Roman War by various terms:

- Great Revolt
- 70AD
- AD70
- the day of the LORD

Etc.

Which would be most user-friendly term for the Tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tags are all lowercase, so AD70 and 70AD show as ad70, 70ad (both of which look a little odd. I'd suggest using the same term that's generally used; Wikipedia uses "First Jewish–Roman War" but states that it is ["sometimes called the Great Revolt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_War), which is probably a better length for a tag name. [first-jewish-roman-war](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-jewish-roman-war) can be proposed as a synonym for [great-revolt](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/great-revolt).

Comment: So if I put "great-revolt" as a tag and put "70ad" etc in the description will it still be found, just as easily?

Comment: A good tag description would be nice but isn't essential — whereas 70ad isn't very good as a tag name, it could still be a synonym which will mean that if someone starts typing it the great-revolt tag will be suggested.

Comment: Okay, so I just need to come up with all the appropriate aliases then. Thanks.

Comment: I just created a tag "great-jewish-revolt". I didn't see how to add an alias. May I trouble you to add these aliases or show me how?  70ad, first-jewish-roman-war. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator I added the synonyms. That takes 5+ high rep user's voting on them or a moderator. Also note usually creating tag synonyms would be something that is done _after_ there is a demonstrated need to simplify or disambiguate, not before. For the most part just pick the best tag name and run with it and cleanup and strays that pop up. If the same stray duplicates keep showing up then you setup a synonym and merge.